# CSS: How to align differently sized images in a line?

Tags: css

I am trying to align differently sized images in a line using the vertical-align property as well as by keeping top:50%

Now it does solve the problem partially as all the images are vertically in the middle but due to the different sizes of the images they are not aligned "like pearls on a string"

I want to somehow make images go top:50% from the centre of the image not it's border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my simple example which uses jquery

http://jsbin.com/ekazo3